# why Tomcat check file integrity

Tags: java, tomcat

When we download Tomcat, installation guide says "You must verify the integrity of the downloaded files". I just want to know, WHY?

We never check file integrity by hand when we download any file from internet, but for Tomcat, we need to do it. Does Tomcat have some special reason?

Comment: `We never check file integrity by hand when we download any file from internet` Why not?

Comment: *"We never check file integrity"* That's how you get **hacked**. You don't *have to* do it any more for Tomcat, but they do provide the *security* of doing so, for your safety.

Comment: Since this is a general "why check file integrity" question and not one specifically relating to Tomcat as a programming tool, I think it's off topic here (and possibly more suited to Super User?)

Comment: In fact: http://superuser.com/questions/326959/how-do-i-check-the-checksum-of-a-download-and-why-should-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always verify the integrity of any file you download over the internet; an attacker may have modified it in nefarious ways. Verifying the signature ensures that you

1. Have the entire file
2. It wasn't tampered with.

Comment: All true but I've never done it in my life. Have you?

Comment: @EJP Yes. Especially back in [2010](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2517227/enterprise-applications/apache-project-server-hacked--passwords-compromised.html).